# Bitrate calculator GUI for Linux

Tags: linux, video, gui, calculator

I'm looking for a simple bitrate calculator with GUI for Linux (for use to video encoding), but not found. Please, what are the applications with GUI to calculate a bitrate for Linux (any distribution)? With many options input like resolution, bitrate, size... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I ansmer to myself. There is an application that do the job I wish with a nice GUI :

**Bitrate calculator GPL for Linux on GitHub :**

[image: capture linux]

**https://github.com/Philippe734/Bitrate-calculator**

For input, we can set the bitrate, the file size desired, the bits/(pixel*frame) and up to 3 audios channels. I installed it easily with the instructions from the author.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without more information, but will [divxcomp](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/divxcomp) do the job?

[image: Calculate DivX bitrate 0.1]

Comment: This is the kind of app I wish. Thanks. This app has few options (no bitrate entry) and difficult to install easily, I continue to search.

Comment: Could you update your question to include what Linux distribution you are using?

Comment: Question updated : any distribution, because I'm using several distro